# nested_form displays a partial twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms, nested-form-for

I'm using the gem nested_form in a Rails 3.1 application. The problem is that when I click on the link generated by "link_to_add", it displays the partial twice, whereas it should display it just once. There you go some code:

Form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :safety_info_files %>
  # adds a link for displaying the template
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add file", :safety_info_files %>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Template:

```
<div class="fields">
  <%= f.link_to_remove "remove" %><br />
  <%= f.label :doc, "File" %>
  <%= f.file_field :doc %><br />
</div>
```

Did anybody else have the same problem?

EDIT:

Silly mistake, silly me. Sorry if I made some of you wasting time, the problem was that I was loading "nested_form.js" twice, so it called the function that appended the partial the same number of times.

Sorry again.

Comment: How did you resolve the loading twice?  Was it two copies of the file, or was it sprockets related?

Comment: ZMorek it was a really silly mistake, I had required nested_forms.js in my application.js (through 'require_tree .') and then loaded it again explicitly (using the javascript_include_tag). Are you having a similar problem?

Comment: I put `nested_forms.js` into `/vendor/assets/javascripts/` and somehow it seems like it's loading twice. I didn't add a tag, but it's in my `application.js`.  I've tinkered with it a couple times, I think I might need to try a few more variants, delete the compiled files then compile again.

Comment: running "rails g nested_form:install" automatically adds nested_forms.js to /public/javascripts, did you remove it after copying it to vendor? What's the content of your application.js?

Comment: @davids - you should answer your question and mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly mistake, silly me. Sorry if I made some of you wasting time, the problem was that I was loading "nested_form.js" twice, so it called the function that appended the partial the same number of times.

Answer (score 1):

For those having this issue using rails 4 / turbolinks and not finding nested_form.js included twice, try removing turbolinks from application.js. Once I did this and bounced the server this issue was resolved.

Credit here: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/issues/307

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.

I had included nested_form.js in my application layout file.

And I haven't changed my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file, it is as it is, when it was created at time of creating rails application.

When I removed entry from my application layout, problem was solved.